# appending values in a global map in clojure

Tags: clojure

I declared a map in clojure using

```
             (def finalMap {})
```

I am appending values to it inside a function using assoc but they are not appending, the map is remaining empty. I think it is due to immutability, can I in some way make a global map mutable.The function is a recursive one and I am appending values each time the function is called.

```
          (defn func [arg1 arg2]
            ;(map append inside let)
            (dorun (for [i (range 0 index)]
              (do
                (func(arg1 arg2))))))
```

Can you help me with the correct way to do this?

Comment: the solution for this one is to use `atom` as proposed in the answer. More important is what is your final goal? could you provide the context the function would be used in? maybe there is a better solution, not involving mutable data.

Comment: by the way: `(dorun (for [i (range 0 index)] ...` could be shortened to `(dotimes [i index] ...` , and `do` inside `dorun` is obsolete, since the body of `do*` macros is evaluated in an implicit `do` block.

Comment: Actually I just started using clojure and was convertng a java code to clojure. I implemented this function the same way I did in java. Obviously there must be a way in clojure to do this without using mutable maps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a *mutable map* then you should create an atom:

```
(def final-map (atom {}))
```

Also normally you would use `assoc` to add more key value pairs to it. However you will need to use `swap!` just to be able to call `assoc`:

```
(swap! final-map assoc :a "a value")
```

This will add a key/value pair where the key is the keyword `:a` and the value is the String "a value".

It might be good to view some other [examples of using assoc](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/assoc). Realise that in the code above `assoc` is being called with the *old* value of `final-map` as its first argument, and returning the *new* value of `final-map`.

Comment: Yeah thank you. I did the same using ref. It is working now.

Comment: You can write whole applications with just one atom. And if you only have one then there's no need to use a ref: see [here](http://tarynsauer.tumblr.com/post/77631451200/clojure-should-i-use-atoms-or-refs) - and realise the author did not need to use two atoms - he/she could have had the atom as a map with two key/value pairs.

Comment: Oh I will look into it.Thank you.

Comment: And another thing to think about is always reaching for `map` (as it looks like you tried) when you want to do something multiple times. Consider `(map inc (range 10))`.